# How to analyze the convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+4}{n^2-3n+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I know it's by comparison test,but i can't figure out how to operate this fraction

Comment: Find a constant $K>0$ and an $N$ such that for $n\ge N$ then ${n+4 \over n^2-3n+1 } \ge {K \over n}$. From there you can find a harmonious conclusion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the comparison test, since $\displaystyle \frac{n+4}{n^2 - 3n + 1}$ is positive for $n \geq 3$.  Notice that $(n+4)^2 = n^2 + 8n + 16 > n^2 - 3n + 1$.

And the divergence of $\displaystyle \sum \frac{1}{n+4}$ can be established with, e.g., the integral test.

Comment: You need $n\ge3$ so that $n^2-3n+1>0$. Minor point.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I totally missed that.  Thanks @JohnWaylandBales

Answer (score 1):

You may use limit comparison test; compare with the harmonic series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an additional direct comparison approach:

For $n\ge1$ we have $4n>-3n+1$ so adding $n^2$ we get

\begin{eqnarray}
n^2+4n&>&n^2-3n+1\\
n(n+4)&>&n^2-3n+1
\end{eqnarray}

For $n\ge3$ the right side of the inequality is positive so we get

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{n+4}{n^2-3n+1}>\dfrac{1}{n}
\end{equation}

So the series converges by direct comparison to the harmonic series.